# Detect pasted input with Readline NodeJs

Tags: node.js, input, copy-paste

We are using Node JS and the `readline` lib. We are trying to detect all keypresses to simlulate a terminal. But we want to treat copy-paste input as a single string. How can we do that with the readline library. This is a snippet of our code:

```
const readline = require('readline');
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on('keypress', (_, key) => {
    this.logger.debug(JSON.stringify(key));
    terminal.writeString(key.sequence)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior by using timeouts. Add the key input to a list and after a certain amount of time pass that list to your input handler.

The code below should explain itself.

```js
const readline = require('readline');
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);

// increase value for slower / older devices, 3 is enough for me
const maxInputDelay = 3;

// internal values
let keyInput = [];
let timeoutId = -1;

process.stdin.on('keypress', (_, key) => {
    // add key to input array
    keyInput.push(key /*.sequence*/);

    // reset the timer for each new input received
    if (timeoutId !== -1) clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    // send the input to a function after a certain amount of time has passed
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        // handle input and clear array
        handleInput(keyInput);
        keyInput = [];
    }, maxInputDelay)
});

// handle input
function handleInput(keys) {
    console.log("input received:", keys, `isPaste = ${keys.length > 1}`)

    // your code goes here
}
```